# Conditional filename in webpack config output

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

my current webpack output config is as follows:

```
output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: '/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '/[chunkhash].js'
}
```

However, I have one entry file (custom.js) that I don't want to add [chunkhash] suffix. all others I do want to add the chuckhash suffix after the file name. Essentially:

```js
if (name is 'custom') {
    filename: '/[name].js'
} else {
    filename: '/[name].[chunkhash].js'
}
```

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Depending on your constraints, the easiest way to do this is probably to just have multiple configurations.

Comment: can you elaborate. I am currently using two separate config for dev and production but I am not sure how to do it based on entry point

Comment: When do you want to have hash with name?  in dev or prod env?

Answer (score 12):

From https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename:

module.exports = {

```
  //...
  output: {
    filename: ({ chunk: { name } }) => {
      return name === 'main' ? '[name].js': '[name]/[name].js';
    },
  }
};
```

Comment: For what version of webpack is that? Are there limitations? I'm trying to use it in the path (instead of the filename) and it just says "configuration.output.path should be a string", and fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that (webpack 4.x):

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: (arg) => {
        if (arg.chunk.name == "vendor") {
            return '[name].[chunkhash].js';
        }
        return '[name].js';
    } ,
    publicPath: `/${common.APP_ROOT}/`
},
```

Comment: Looks like a function argument to chunkFilename is no longer valid, only a string is supported in the latest docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-chunkfilename

Comment: webpack 5 still supports functions for `chunkFilename`: `function (pathData, assetInfo) => string`

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you can have only one output configuration.

> Options affecting the output of the compilation. output options tell
>   Webpack how to write the compiled files to disk. Note, that while
>   there can be multiple entry points, only one output configuration is
>   specified.

So I guess you cannot do that for now (at least according to the docs). Can you elaborate why do you need something like that ?